# With Neo4j [subquery?], how to get all related nodes only if they are in some way unique?

Tags: neo4j, subquery, max

I have Providers who produce Products which are of a certain Category. I would like to find out how often a Category Product has the most expensive Price for a Provider (easy), and there are no other Products of other Categories for that Provider with the same Price (difficult). In other words, for each Category, how many Providers offer a Product of this Category at a higher Price than every other Product of a different Category they have to offer.

That seems to require a subquery, so I have come up with this:

```
MATCH (price:Price)-[:COSTS]-(product:Product)-[:IS_BY]->(provider:Provider)
WITH max(price.amount) as max, min(price.amount) as min, provider
MATCH (product:Product)-[:IS_BY]->(provider)
MATCH (product)-[:IS_OF_CATEGORY]->(category:Category)
MATCH (price2:Price)-[:COSTS]-(product:Product)
WHERE price2.amount = max AND price2.amount > min
RETURN count(category.name) as count, category.name ORDER BY count DESC
```

That tells me how many times each Category is the most expensive one for a Provider, and that that Provider has other Products from other Categories that are cheaper. **In other words, that SOME of the other Products from other Categories are cheaper, but not that ALL of the other Products from other Categories are cheaper**...

Any ideas at all?

Comment: Why not have `price` as a property on `Product`, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but I'll give it a shot!

I think you're saying: For each category, find/count all of the producers which offer have that category as their highest priced category.

This should give you a breakdown of the max price per product and category:

```
MATCH
  (price:Price)-[:COSTS]-(product:Product)-[:IS_BY]->(provider:Provider),
  (product)-[:IS_OF_CATEGORY]->(category:Category)
RETURN category, provider, max(amount) AS max_amount
```

To find out which category is the highest-priced category for each provider:

```
MATCH
  (price:Price)-[:COSTS]-(product:Product)-[:IS_BY]->(provider:Provider),
  (product)-[:IS_OF_CATEGORY]->(category:Category)
WITH provider, category, max(amount) AS max_amount
ORDER BY max(amount) DESC
RETURN provider, collect(category)[0] AS highest_priced_category
```

To find the count of providers for each category that have that category as their highest priced category:

```
MATCH
  (price:Price)-[:COSTS]-(product:Product)-[:IS_BY]->(provider:Provider),
  (product)-[:IS_OF_CATEGORY]->(category:Category)
WITH provider, category, max(amount) AS max_amount
ORDER BY max(amount) DESC
WITH provider, collect(category)[0] AS highest_priced_category
RETURN highest_priced_category, count(provider)
```

Does that work?

**EDIT**: Taking another stab based on your comment:

```
MATCH
  (price:Price)-[:COSTS]-(product:Product)-[:IS_BY]->(provider:Provider),
WITH provider, product ORDER BY price.amount DESC
WITH provider, collect(product)[0]
  (product)-[:IS_OF_CATEGORY]->(category:Category)
RETURN category, count(provider)
```

This finds all of the Products/Prices for a Provider and for each Provider gets the highest priced product.  Then it matches to find the Category for that Product and returns the number of providers for each Category

Comment: Thanks Brian! Sorry for the crap description of the problem. :) What I was looking to find is: for each category, for how many providers are products of this category more expensive than of any other category. So it's not just that it's equal to max, but also that everything else for that provider is less than max.

Comment: Just put in an edit that may be the answer.  If that doesn't work, maybe editing to post some sample data and a sample result that you'd be looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, that gets me the first priciest product, but I want the category to be returned ONLY IF it "stands out", i.e. its product is the priciest, and no other product of another category matches that price. Sorry for being unable to explain this better!